# How to export an Easeljs stage or container

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, easeljs

I have an Easeljs stage that contains various shapes. A simplified demo can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/gjhmLwkw/

```
var circle = new createjs.Shape();
circle.graphics
    .setStrokeStyle(1)
    .beginStroke("rgba(0,0,0,1)")
    .drawCircle(100,100,100);
stage.addChild(circle);
```

How can I export the current state of the stage? The aim is to import the data at a later date to recreate the stage.

I thought this would be fairy straightforward. Perhaps my approach is wrong. The jsfiddle has my thinking at the end.

```
stage.children.forEach(function(shape) {
    var instructions = shape.graphics.getInstructions();
    instructions.forEach(function(instruction) {
        console.log(instruction);
    });
});
```

Comment: You would have to serialize everything, right down to the instruction properties, and then write a deserialize to recreate it. There is nothing like this currently, but it could be an interesting helper utility to add to the library.

Comment: @Lanny now that's the thing, how can I serialize those command objects? The properties are no problem, but how would I identify each class E.g. "Graphics.Fill"?

Comment: @Lanny I guess the approach might to to extend each command class with serialize/deserialize functions. E.g. Graphics.Fill.prototype.serialize ?

Comment: Yes. Currently the command classes aren't even clonable. Definitely some work to do there.